# Rails app site wide settings editable from the front end

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

I have a small **Rails 4.2** app, that has a few settings that I would like to be changed site wide e.g
`start_time: time, finish_time: time, disabled: boolean`

Im aware I could make a model called `AppSettings` and have those fields in it but I would only want one instance available, as these are supposed to be site wide

What is the accepted method of doing this pattern?

I should also mention that these settings need to be updatable from the front end.

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that I have updated the original question

Comment: Have you considered adding methods to `ApplicationController`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Rails' new custom configuration is what you'd want depending on your use case.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/611849772dd66c2e4d005dcfe153f7ce79a8a7db

`Rails.configuration.x.start_time = Time.now`

and so on. You'd be able to access this configuration from anywhere in the app and there would only be one instance of it at any point in time.

If this does not fit your use case there might be other options.

**EDIT**

In order to actually answer the updated question of the OP, I can think of two ways to achieve a persisted set of configurations.

**A row per configuration value**

Create a model/table with a column for a setting `name` and the setting `value`

Then your model could make sure and validate that there's only one row per setting and ensure that the settings are read/written properly.

```
class AppSettings < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate_uniqueness_of :name

  def self.[](setting_name)
    find_by_name(setting_name) or raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, "cannot find setting for #{setting_name}"
  end
end
```

Two downsides of this is that you'd need to make sure that each setting is converted to their proper type and you'd be hitting the database every time you want a setting.

**Single row table**

This would allow you to have a column per setting but the downside is you need to ensure only one row is in the table unless you want multiple combination of settings in your app logic.

In order to ensure that only one row is used you'd have to create an interface that only performs queries on that row. Something like this

```
class AppSettings < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current
    first_or_create(setting_one: "default", setting_two: "another")
  end
end
```

You'd then just need to make sure that any time you use the `AppSettings` model is through the `current` class method.

Comment: This is a really nice addition. thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention these fields need to updateable from a front end form and stored in the db

Comment: @SamMason you should edit the question with that little tidbit. And since you want to store these settings in the DB you should create a model for it.

Comment: Thanks @mmichael I have just updated the title, how do I make sure that the model only saves one instance of the model?

Comment: Will you really have a table to store only 1 record? Do you really need to persist this on the database or is it something that you can keep in memory?

Comment: I admit it would be easier to store as a config var but the person using it isnt very well versed with coding

Comment: @SamMason well the issue I'm assuming is that they want this configuration to be persisted and be able to be changed. So its not necessarily an app configuration but a business requirement configuration. I'd say a single row table would be ok in this case. I'm not sure how else to approach this. Maybe a configuration file but then if they have more than one instance it would not work.

Comment: Thanks for that @LeoCorrea that seems to be the correct thing Im looking for, how would I go about limiting the table to only allowing one row. If you submitted answer I would be happy to mark as correct/accepted

Comment: @LeoCorrea - in the one row per configuration option, where would I initialize the settings if not already set? Just from seeds.rb, or application_controller?

Comment: @Anand it depends on what you're trying to accomplish. You could build an admin interface to update the app settings or make a rake task that initializes it and only run it once since they are good for one-off tasks. Also, remember the suggestions I made are not necessarily the only ways to approach the situation.

Comment: Right now, in my app, I am using the one row per config option - and initializing it manually from console, as well as have ability to change from an admin interface - would be nice to have a better built in idiomatic way of doing this